# Cannot read property 'chromeExOAuthConfig' of null in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing a Chrome extension which will tweet. I am using [Google oAuth tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) for this.

I need help to get authorize user from Twitter. And to save credentials somewhere so that I can use them for tweeting from my app. I am new to this, and I need direction. I have composed following method. To start the authorization process.

But it does not send me to Twitter auth. When I call this authorize method. Am I doing it right?

I need some pointer here. I also have downloaded chrome_ex_oauth.html. Which will be called as callback. Right?

I dont know... when I will got those access token and secrets to save them against every authorized user and use them for tweeting.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>  

 jQuery(function() {

            var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
                  'request_url': 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
                  'authorize_url': 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
                  'access_url': 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
                  'consumer_key': '---',
                  'consumer_secret': '---',
                  'scope': '',
                  'app_name': 'Tweet'
                });
            jQuery('#connect').click(function (){

                oauth.authorize(install);       
            });
        });

        function install() {
          alert('success')
        }

        function callback(resp, xhr) {
          // ... Process text response ...
        };
```

**Edit:**

My `oauth.authorize` get called. And redirect page appears. But it stuck on 'Redirecting...'. Error console shows following error.

Cannot read property 'chromeExOAuthConfig' of null
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the Chrome OAuth tutorial really bloated and indirect.  I just put up an extension that pulls private GitHub data using OAuth2.

[Here is the source](https://github.com/jjNford/github-repositories/blob/master/js/oauth2.js) (be sure to also look at injection.js and adapter.html - both are independent of jQuery and required).

I essentially just reversed engineered this [solution](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions) to fit just my needs.

What's happening is:

1. You request authorization with your application ID.
2. Twitter will make the user sign in and authorize the application.
3. Twitter will redirect you to the given redirect param that was specified (if you don't want to worry about your extension depending on a webpage or server I would specify the redirect to hit https://twitter.com/robots.txt because your extension relies on Twitter, if Twitter is down it won't matter anyways, and this robots.txt page isn't going anywhere)
4. Add a content script to be injected into the redirect url.  Have the script pull the query string and append it to the adapter page url and redirect to it.
5. In the adapter page load rip the access code from the query string and send a request to Twitter with the access code and your application secret.  You will receive a callback from Twitter providing the users access token if everything was done correctly.
6. Save the token to the extensions local storage, close the adapter page and you are good

Now when the popup opens, you can get the OAuth2 token from the local storage to use with the Twitter API.

[Here is more detail about the OAuth2 flow.](http://oauth.net/2/)

**ANSWER TO YOUR UPDATE**

From what I can see in your console it looks as if the background page is not found.  Does your extension have a background page running?  If so and this is newly added you should reload the extension using the reload button next the the extension at chrome://extensions.  Chrome is very picky when you alter things declared in the manifest and usually requires a reload.  But the chrome.extensions.getBackgroundPage() is a standard API call, so this returning null is an issue.

Have you looked into my solution?  It works very well, really fast and the adapter page can be customized to show loading progress for slower connections (users like feedback).  It also does not rely on jQuery.  You probably won't notice the difference but loading the jQuery library into a redirect page will make the transaction take longer because the script must be pulled in.

Comment: @ jjNford I was messing that whether I can get my stuff running or not. I have reloaded my extension in Chrome preferences, many times. But it gives me the same error. If it's not getting resolve, I will see your code to start it again.

Comment: @ jjNford here is my manifest file: `{
  "name": "Tweet from Chrome",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Tweet from Chrome.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
 "http://ajax.googleapis.com",
 "http://*.twitter.com/*",
  "clipboardWrite"
  ]
}` I am on another background page (I call it settings) where user will add it's twitter account. It's not my main background page.

Comment: @TahirAkram Ah, the problem is that you do not have a background page declared in the manifest.  When you are calling chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() the API is looking for the background page declared in the manifest. This is why you are getting a null value. Look at this link to see how to declare the background page: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

Comment: @TahirAkram you do not need to open the background page in your popup.  A background page by definition is a long running script page that is created when an instance of chrome is started.  So your background page is already up and running before you open the popup.  I would separate out the background processing and your settings page.  Again... my method would require no background page... this is nice because you can guarantee users that you have no process running in the background thus not wasting their cpu and battery.  Users like to hear this.

Comment: @ jjNford 404 on your link. Can you make it available back? So that I can use that solution. Thanks.

Comment: @TahirAkram https://github.com/jjNford/oauth2-chrome-extension - Here you go, this is a project dedicated to your request.  Don't forget to read the documentation so you can alter anything that requires it.